# Getting DSN architecture mismatch between Excel and ODBC MySql Connector

Tags: mysql, excel, odbc

I'm getting the following error using Excel trying to add an external data source to the spreadsheet.

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application.

I can't find a compatibility chart between MySql and the MySql-ODBC Connector versions, but I got the latest that I could find.  This is what I'm using:

mysql: 5.6.16 winx64
ConnectorODBC: 5.3.2x64

I've tried both the Ansi and Unicode versions of the driver.  When adding it using the Windows Administrative Tools->Data Sources (ODBC) link the Test button says it connected successfully.

Data Source Name: Loans
TCP/IP server: localhost
Port: 3306
User: 
Password: 
Database: Loans

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 10):

Your problem is that your client, Excel, is 32bit and needs to connect to a 32bit ODBC driver. Your 32bit ODBC driver will connect to a 64bit app just fine, what's important is that the client connects to a driver with the same architecture. On %windir%\syswow64 you'll find a file called odbcad32.exe, it's your 32bit ODBC control panel, add your 32bit MySQL ODBC driver there and use that to connect.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.  I didn't think that Excel would have been 32 bits.